# YouTube Data Search API with no query

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a question about the Search endpoint:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

You can run this without specifying a query (q) parameter, in fact without specifying almost anything.

My question is - if I run the API request with only type=channel or type=video, how will the API decide what to return?

Answer (score 0):

It will return whatever you indicate in the "`fields`" parameter. You can try it here in [Youtube API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&type=video&fields=etag%252CeventId%252Citems%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CregionCode%252CtokenPagination%252CvisitorId&_h=1&)), just click Execute.

You can see the list of parameter you can use for fields [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource).

Comment: I believe that for each result returned, that will affect what information comes back.

What I am asking about is how the API will decide what results come back?

To put it another way, if we think of the API as returning a table, I am trying to understand how the API decides what rows to return (not columns).